# How to add 2 buttons to <li> via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-button

I am using http://jsfiddle.net/eLENj/493/ as a guide line to create 2 stacked buttons in an li element.

This is the code I am using

```
            '<li><div class="ui-grid-a">' +
                '<div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 75%;">' +
                    '<div data-role="fieldcontain">' +
                        '<h3>Address Details:</h3>' +
                            '<p>Address 1</p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 25%; float: right;">' +
                    '<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="height: 20px;">' +
                        '<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="map">Map</a>' +
                        '<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>' +
                    '</div>' + 
                '</div>' +   
            '</div>' +
            '</li>').listview('refresh');
```

But what I end up with are two "regular" hyperlinks which look like "MapDelete". Any ideas why the buttons are not being rendered correctly?

Comment: do you have a reference to query.mobile-1.0.1.min.css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method listview('refresh') will style ONLY a listview.

Because buttons are not part of a listview they will be disregarded.

You will need to style them separately like this:

```
$('[data-role="button"]').button();
```

Or you can use this method on your content DIV:

```
$('#contentDivID').trigger('create');
```

If you want to find more about this topic take a look at my other blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)** describing how to enhance dynamically added jQuery Mobile content.

**EDIT :**

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UDBCM/

You will need to position them by yourself + find some custom map icon.